# How can I create variables like registers?

Tags: pic, c, register, xc8

I'm currently working on a small home alarm system that runs on the PIC16F628A microcontroller. It's not the first time I came to a project with the idea of using my own custom created registers that work exactly like the hardware registers, in the way that I can modify the whole register in one line or change the individual "parameters" of the register (ex: PORTAbits.RA0).

In the Microchip Developer Help there is a section called "Bit fields", under [Bits, Bools, and Bit-fields](https://microchipdeveloper.com/c:bits-bools-and-bit-fields) wich talks about what seems like the closest implementation of a custom register, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. In the example, you always have to write the name of the union, followed by a dot, and then, one of the bits or the whole register. It is nice, but I'm looking to not have to use the dot always, just only when I need to write the individual bits (and also, using the "bits" postfix).

I've also decided to take a look at one of the definition of the registers, just to see how could I find a way around:

```
// Register: TRISA
#define TRISA TRISA
extern volatile unsigned char           TRISA               __at(0x085);
#ifndef _LIB_BUILD
asm("TRISA equ 085h");
#endif
// bitfield definitions
typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned TRISA0                 :1;
        unsigned TRISA1                 :1;
        unsigned TRISA2                 :1;
        unsigned TRISA3                 :1;
        unsigned TRISA4                 :1;
        unsigned TRISA5                 :1;
        unsigned TRISA6                 :1;
        unsigned TRISA7                 :1;
    };
} TRISAbits_t;
extern volatile TRISAbits_t TRISAbits __at(0x085);
// bitfield macros
...
```

In this definition, the advantage is that the memory address is known, so two variables can share the same memory address, but keep their different names.
Is there any way I can achieve the same thing as hardware registers, but stored in the data memory?

Comment: `two variables can share the same memory address, but keep their different names` ... do you realize that they also share the content?

Comment: Be aware that your micro has single-cycle instructions (BSF, BCF) to implement bit access on registers but not on memory. That means that an interrupt can happen halfway through a bit update on your "custom register", which you don't have to worry about when accessing bits of hardware registers.

Comment: @ThePhoton does that mean that if an interrupt occurs at mid-update on one of my custom registers, data could potentially not be saved? or i'll just have "unexpected behaviour" if my interrupts use those custom registers?

Comment: The main risk would be if the interrupt handler also writes the "registers".

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for the advice. I'll try to avoid writing operations of my registers on interrupts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the magic of pointers, macros, structs & unions!

```C
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
  unsigned bit0 : 1;
  unsigned bit1 : 1;
  unsigned bit2 : 1;
  unsigned bit3 : 1;
  unsigned bit4 : 1;
  unsigned bit5 : 1;
  unsigned bit6 : 1;
  unsigned bit7 : 1;
} reg_bits_t;                                   // typedef a struct containing 8 individual
                                                // single-bit bit-field members

uint8_t myRegister;                             // define an unsigned 8-bit variable
                                                // at some unspecified memory location
                                                // (decided by the compiler/linker)
                                                // doesn't matter where it is

reg_bits_t * const pMyReg = (reg_bits_t *)&myRegister; // define a constant pointer 
                                                // to a reg_bits_t union and initialize
                                                // that pointer to the memory address of the
                                                // previously defined myRegister variable

#define myRegBits (*pMyReg)                     // define a macro to dereference the pMyReg
                                                // union pointer (not strictly necessary)

void SomeFunction(void)
{
  myRegister = 0x12;    // as you would expect, myRegister now contains 0x12

  myRegBits.bit3 = 1;   // we set bit3, in the same memory space as myRegister
                        // so myRegister now contains 0x1a

  if (myRegBits.bit4 == 1)  // since myRegister == 0x12, it's bit4 is set (0x10)
  {
    // do something
  }

  // etc ...
}
```

The macro `#define myRegBits (*pMyReg)` is not strictly necessary.
You could just as easily access the bits using the `->` operator on `pMyReg` directly:
`pMyReg->bit6 = 1;`

You could also define a macro which creates both the variable and pointer together with one line of code:

```C
#define DEFINE_REGISTER(_regName) \
  uint8_t _regName;               \
  reg_bits_t * const _regName##Bits = (reg_bits_t *)&_regName;

DEFINE_REGISTER(myReg1);
DEFINE_REGISTER(myReg2);
DEFINE_REGISTER(myReg3);
```

but you then only have the option of using the `->` operator to access the individual bits (unless you also define additional macros for each register):

```C
myReg1 = 0x66;
myReg1Bits->bit4 = 1;

myReg2 = 0x99;
myReg2Bits->bit6 = 1;
```

All of this also works just as well on wider variables, just use a `uint16_t` or `uint32_t` and add extra bits to the `reg_bits_t` bitfield struct.
You're also free to use the built-in types like `char`, `short`, etc. instead of `uint8_t`,  `uint16_t`, etc.
I just prefer the `<stdint.h>` types because the size and signedness is explicitly defined in the name.

Another option would be to use a union to "wrap" a bit-field struct and a simple variable together, and then define a macro to "hide" the "unioniness":

```C
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union
{
  uint8_t regVal;
  struct
  {
    unsigned bit0 : 1;
    unsigned bit1 : 1;
    unsigned bit2 : 1;
    unsigned bit3 : 1;
    unsigned bit4 : 1;
    unsigned bit5 : 1;
    unsigned bit6 : 1;
    unsigned bit7 : 1;
  } regBits;
} my_reg_t;

my_reg_t myRegUnion;
#define myRegVal    myRegUnion.regVal    // define a macro to access the regVal
                                         // in myRegUnion
#define myRegBits   myRegUnion.regBits   // define a macro to access the regBits
                                         // bitfield in myRegUnion

void SomeFunction(void)
{
  myRegVal = 0x34;
  myRegBits.bit1 = 1;                   // register now contains 0x35
}
```

or a slightly more advanced version which doesn't require you to define separate macros for each 'register' you use, using the same union typedef as above:

```C
my_reg_t myReg1;
my_reg_t myReg2;
my_reg_t myReg3;
#define myRegVal(_x)   _x.regVal
#define myRegBits(_x)  _x.regBits

void SomeFunction(void)
{
  myRegVal(myReg1) = 0x45;
  myRegBits(myReg1).bit7 = 1;

  myRegVal(myReg2) = 0x88;
  myRegBits(myReg2).bit4 = 1;

  // etc
}
```

Depending on the underlying architecture of the MCU you do this on, some of these single-bit operations might be more or less 'code efficient' than others.
Many PICs for example have assembler instructions dedicated to manipulating single bits, and also may have "bit-banded" blocks in their memory maps where you're given different "windows" into the same memory where one "window" lets you read & write whole bytes while another "window" lets you read & write individual bits - both actually accessing the same physical underlying memory location.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I decided to use the first option with `union`, but I do have some questions. Should I use the `volatile` type to prevent the compiler doing [unexpected things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246148)? and also, Imagine I decide to have a lot of registers that are uint8_t, and the only thing that differs from one to another is the individual bit names. Should I create as many `typedef union` as I need? or should I instead create as many `#define` as different bit names I have? see an example [here](https://gist.github.com/ffpp2003/d5945c53ca1ef79dbae371192ea96041)